# SQL partially join

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have problem with SQL join.

I have two tables. table1: name, sth. table2:name,sth.

What I would like to do is to find rows in table2, whose name contains table1.name. e.g such rows should be selected:

```
table1.name = aa. table2.name = aab
```

I wrote a query:

```
select *
from table1 
inner join table2 on table2.name like '%'+table1.name+'%'
```

It returns the error

> [42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 2:3 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN ''%''

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks very much

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please add back the tags for the database you are really using.

Comment: What does "fails" mean?

Comment: returns the error:[42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 2:3 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN ''%''

Comment: Can you give an example with data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
select * 
from table1 t1 
where exists (select 1 
              from table2 t2 
              where t2.name like '%'+t1.name+'%')
```